# Does Harmonic Series Converge to a Function of n?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist a function f(n) which the harmonic series converge to?

For example, does it converge to

ln(n) + c, where c is a constant, or 0.5(ln(n)+ln(n+1)), or something else?

Comment: Your question is not clear: if you take limit as n tends to infinity, this limit cannot depend on n....

Answer (score 3):

The [asymptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion) behaviour of the harmonic series is that as the number of terms increases, it approaches the function $\gamma + \log n + \frac{1}{2n}$, where $\gamma \approx 0.577$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant). For sufficiently large $n$, you can drop the last term and still have an adequate approximation.

Answer (score 1):

At least, we can say that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k =_{n\to +\infty} \ln n+\gamma +o\left(\frac 1n\right)$$
where $\gamma\simeq 0.57$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

NB: $\displaystyle f(n)=_{n\to +\infty} o(g(n))\iff \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}=0$.

Comment: Under the equivalence you define (limit of ratios is 1), the Euler-Mascheroni constant is irrelevant here...

Comment: Good remark. I improved my answer.